# iOS Lock a UIView in place under the Nav Bar and above a UITableView via storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have used the `storyboard` to lay out my GUI objects.  So I have a `UITableViewController` that contains a Table View and a Navigation Bar. The Table View contains a View and the Table View Cells.  The View contains a `UITextField`, a `UIButton` and a `UILabel`.

When the app is run everything displays how I would like it, and the View is sitting underneath the Nav Bar and above the first cell of the Table.  The problem occurs when you scroll.  The View (with the Text Field, Button and Label) is scrolling too.  I would like for the View to be locked in place and for the table cells to scroll under it.

I think that i may need to implement some code in `scrollViewDidScroll`: inside my `UITableViewController .m` file, but I am really not sure.  I would prefer a solution that allows me to use the `storyboard` to lay out my GUI objects and then wire them up with some supporting code rather than doing the whole thing programatically.

I was going to include an image of how I have laid things out in the `storyboard` but I as a new user I am not allowed to :-(

Thanks in advance :-)

PS: If you try to drag the `UIView` out from being inside the `UITableViewController` then IB places the view at the same level as the First Responder and View Controller and then I don't even see the `UIView` if I run the app.

Comment: how did you create you UITableViewController?

Comment: In the storyboard - all the GUI objects have been created using the storyboard.

Comment: check the two answers, maybe your answer is there.

Comment: @luyuan the answers say the same thing.

Comment: Yes. Did you directly drag a UITableViewController from the storyboard? Or by dragging a UIViewController and then dragging a UIView and a UITableView into it?

Comment: I dragged a UITableViewController, which gave me the UITableView for free, so to speak. When I was digging around trying to solve this I have seen code added to scrollViewDidScroll: but I couldn't figure out how to change it to get it to work with my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can drag the view out from being inside the `UITableViewController`. But make sure that you are not create the `UITableViewController` directly by dragging a `UITableViewController` from `storyboard`. You can create a new `UIViewController` and drag a `tableview` and a `view` into it. Remember to set the `delegate` and `datasource` of the `tableview` to the `UIViewController`. Then the view is locked there.

Comment: Thanks and thanks @MattS too. I implemented this and it works. I did it all in the storyboard.  I didn't bother with the View in the end.  I just used a UIViewController and added the UITextField to that, and then positioned a UITableView under it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController` and create and manage the table view as you would without Storyboard.  I had this happen in the app I'm currently working on and that's the only fix I was able to find.

Comment: Thanks.  This may be the way that I have to go.  It's a pain that you cant add the View in the storyboard to UITableViewController (but then again I suppose its job is to look after Table Views) and when it is added to the UITableView there doesn't seem to be any easy way to lock it's position. It would be nice to keep a visual representation of all my GUI objects in IB.